# To be v3 confusing usage

Tags: passive-voice

I was scrolling through, and I confused when I saw this post, I dont understand Why " to be returned" used here.

What tense is it ?

What's that "to" for ?

We see end of the cartoon's " To be continued " And it means next episode will come, I mean it is future tense. But here I dont think this text is implying to future time.

.[image: To be returned]

Comment: You're on the right track thinking about "future" here. But it's *the future in the **past*** - that's to say ***when it was banned***, the mass protests and subsequent reinstatement lay in the future. Think of *only to be returned* as a slightly stylised was of saying ***but later it was returned***. But I have to say I don't much like the "passive" use of "to be returned" in this exact context - I'd prefer either (active) ***only to return*** or (passive) ***only to be reinstated***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I can imagine using 'only to be' in conversation - how annoying for you, to do all that work on the project, only to be told that the boss' nephew was getting a bonus for it!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Sure - at least *some* native speakers would have this ***only to be X'ed*** construction in their "productive speech" linguistic toolbox. But I suspect in practice an awful lot more would rarely if ever use it in speech, even if they were perfectly familiar with it in the *written* form (and by hearing it in the "relatively rarefied" speech of careful speakers who make their living contributing to public discourse on radio, TV, etc.). In your example, for instance, ***only to be told*** is a much "higher" register than semantically identical ***and then [to] be told***.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of one of the meanings of 'only':

> adverb
>
> You can use only **before an infinitive** to introduce an event which
> happens immediately after one you have just mentioned, and which is
> rather surprising or unfortunate.

Speedy Gonzalez was banned, **only to be returned** after mass protest.

My brother won $100 on a bet at the racecourse, **only to lose it all** when he was mugged on the way home.

I knew a man who worked hard all his life and retired from work at the age of 65, **only to drop dead** the next day.

[Only (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/only)

Comment: And what you describe as "to be v3" is how we form the passive infinitive in English. _To return_ would be the normal (active) infinitive (something returns); _to be returned_ is the passive infinitive (something is returned).

Comment: Returned by the Cartoon Network? I didn't describe anything as "to be v3".

Comment: No, Michael, you didn't; @Burak Dutar did. Apologies for not clarifying.